# How to create a iOS Ringtone from Mathematica

Tags: sound

Does anyone have any idea how to create a ringtone for an iOS phone from Mathematica?  It appears to be a very (unnecessarily) complicated process, that Apple has recently  obfusticated even more by eliminating iTunes from Mac OS (it's a horrible app, but at least it had the necessary audio codecs to do the trick).

Comment: Does the ringtone have any special format? Can it be an mp3 like in Android? I'm not sure how mathematica would help in this case, when other more specialized programs like Audacity etc exist.

Comment: Hans,  yes it does have a special format.  But its really confusing to understand exactly what it is.  So for example, this: " Ringtones are stored using the MPEG-4 file format, with an extension.m4r. The default audio encoding for iPhone ringtones is AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) supported from 8 to 320 Kbps."  Not sure whether MMAs Audio/Video encoders would be able to export in the correct format - I have tried lots of them, so far without success.  I was hoping an audio specialist might be able to advise.

Comment: Googling around a bit, it seems Audacity with FFmpeg can do that, see https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?t=83522. This link is from an old post, but it says it works. I will have a look to see if it's possible with Mathematica, but I don't have an iPhone, so it'll be tricky to test it.

Comment: In Mathematica, probably the format M4A is the way to go (export then rename to .m4r).

Comment: So I exported an mp3 in MMA using the M4A format and renamed the file extension to .m4r.  The next issue is how to get the iPhone to pick it up.  All the apps I have found ultimately use GarageBand to do this.  But I am finding that GarageBand does not recognize any of the .m4a or .m4r files I created.  So far, I can only get it to work on video files.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to force the iPhone to pick it up. Perhaps you could ask in the superuser or apple stacks. Good luck!